# CSS positioning footer elements (wave image and content)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position, responsive

I want to make a footer like this using React JS

[image]

Here is my Code so far

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="footer-wave">
        <Image
          src={require("../assets/images/wave.png").default}
          className="img-fluid"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="footer-wrapper">
        <div className="footer">
          <div className="footer1">
            <ul>
              <li>Legal Notice</li>
              <li>Terms of Use</li>
              <li>Confidentiality</li>
              <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="footer2">
            <ul>
              <li>Subscribe</li>
              <li>Secure Payment</li>
              <li>Content Directly on Your Browser</li>
              <li>Guaranteed Quality Creation</li>
              <li>Customer Service</li>
              <li>FAQ</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="footer3">
            <p>Follow Us</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Instagram</li>
              <li>Youtube</li>
              <li>Twitter</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

CSS

```
.footer-wrapper {
    background-color: #270327;
}

.footer {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Output :

[image]

I think here positioning elements would do the work, but i tried i am not getting the desired output. Can anyone suggest something? I am new to CSS positioning! Any help would be appreciated !

Wave Image for Reference:

[image]

Comment: Your wave.png needs to have a straight line at the bottom and at the right.

Comment: I was thinking to push the div to the top so that gap can get filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I see the wave image is not quite proper straight closing at the bottom. So best way would be to Photoshop one with proper dimension. You could here to close the gap between footer and image, rotate a little bit via css.

```
.img-fluid {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

To achive the nearest closing between the image and footer you have to set maybe other value as 10deg.

Comment: 10 deg is too much, i did 1 deg, the image is staright now, but i am getting scrollbar

Comment: use `overflow: hidden` in the element you are getting the scrollbar. If the horizontal whole page is impacted, then set to `body`.